# subview not receiving touches in iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIView that responds to a tap (View A). I have a UITableViewController with a UITableView (View B). View B is added as a subview to view A, and View B has a smaller area than View A. So if a user taps inside view B, they can select a row in the table. if they tap outside the table but still inside View A, the View A responds differently (It's a drawer that hides itself).

This worked fine in iOS 5 and 6. However, in iOS7, the View B (UITableview) never seems to receive the touches and the rows never get selected, even though it is a subview of View A. When I disable View A's UITapGestureRecognizer, view B then starts getting the touches, and the user can select the rows in the table (but view A doesn't respond to touches now so this isn't acceptable)

My code hasn't changed. Any thoughts on what might be going wrong here in iOS7? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello R.S... I think this is an autolayout issue.. maybe you could change the background of the tappable are and check where is it exactly.. 



Worked?

Comment: Hi R.S, you can try a couple of things: first if UITableViewCell is created by xib try to add programatically the view B again. Second, you can try to paint viewB and viewB.superview to check they are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle this a couple of ways:

1. You can use [`gestureRecognizerShouldBegin`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizerShouldBegin%3a) of the [`UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html):

   - Specify your view controller as conforming to `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`:

     ```
     @interface ViewController () <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

     ...

     @end
     ```
   - Specify your view controller to actually be the [`delegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/delegate) of the tap gesture recognizer for view A:

     ```
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
     tap.delegate = self;
     [self.viewA addGestureRecognizer:tap];
     ```
   - Write `gestureRecognizerShouldBegin` that returns NO if the location of the tap is contained by the `frame` of `viewB`:

     ```
     - (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
     {
         CGPoint point = [gesture locationInView:self.viewB.superview];

         return !CGRectContainsPoint(self.viewB.frame, point);
     }
     ```
2. You can alternatively, subclass the tap gesture, and change its behavior to fail immediately (i.e. change the state directly to `UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed`) if the location of the tap coincides with the `UITableView` subview.
3. You can also just add a subview to the main view that just covers the space of the main view above the table view, and then add your tap gesture to that, and that way you don't have to deal with any overlapping gesture recognizers.

Comment: Rob, Thanks for the detailed answer. The first suggestion works like a charm! The second one works partially (view A doesn't respond to the gesture, but view B never gets it either). Any idea why this would have broken in IOS7?

Comment: @Rob Ironically, Apple's official method for indicating which should fail (requireGestureRecognizerToFail:) is broken in iOS7 :(. (I came here via Google b/c that method is completely ignored in iOS7, but works perfectly in previous IOS)

Comment: @R.S I know this is an old question, but I realize that my second approach, which entailed changing the gesture state to failed/canceled _after_ the gesture was recognized, would exhibit the behavior you describe. I was just trying to save you from having to write your own gesture recognizer subclass, but in retrospect, if you use that second approach, that's precisely what you have to do. I've revised my answer accordingly. Bottom line, option 1 (or my new option 3) is probably easiest.

Comment: @Adam I just tested `requireGestureRecognizerToFail` on iOS 7.0 and 7.1, and it works fine for me.

Comment: @Rob I haven't worked out why it's failing yet, but it's as simple as switching from ios 6 sim to ios7 sim, and that one call fails. Nothing else changes. Or from any ios6 ipad to any ios7 ipad. I'll report back if/when I discover a difference.